# Basic NN learning XOR tends towards correct answers about half the time, other times it tends to some constant but strange answers

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, theano

I'm just learning Theano, and built a very simple NN that learns XOR. A simple problem should learn fairly quickly. But what I found is that the answer is not correct sometimes, but an oddly specific error.

I'm inputting [[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]] to test the XOR. I should expect a [0,1,1,0] output. And indeed, I get that about half the time.

```
[[ 0.01763905]
 [ 0.99207316]
 [ 0.99207316]
 [ 0.00663723]]
```

But other times I get some sort of combination where two of the outputs are nearly exactly 0.5, one is nearly 1, and the other almost 0. Like so,

```
[[ 0.49998723]
 [ 0.49998723]
 [ 0.99430759]
 [ 0.00622013]]
```

Or something similar like

```
[[ 0.49957245]
 [ 0.98064991]
 [ 0.49957245]
 [ 0.02422073]]
```

Here's my code. Please feel free to let me know if I'm not doing training correctly (as I completely guessed on whether to calculate the gradients for each layer individually)

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np

class HiddenLayer(object):
    def __init__(self, input, layerShape):
        # Input should be matrix of size (batch size, input nodes)
        # Layer shape is (input nodes, hidden nodes)
        self.input = input
        self.W = theano.shared(np.random.normal(0,1,layerShape))
        self.b = theano.shared(np.random.normal(0,1,layerShape[1]))
        self.output = T.nnet.nnet.relu(T.dot(self.input,self.W)+self.b)

    def train(self, cost, rate):
        WGrad = T.grad(cost=cost, wrt=self.W)
        bGrad = T.grad(cost=cost, wrt=self.b)
        return [[self.W, self.W - WGrad * rate],
                [self.b, self.b - bGrad * rate]]


class OutputLayer(object):
    def __init__(self, input, layerShape):
        self.input = input
        self.W = theano.shared(np.random.normal(0,1,layerShape))
        self.b = theano.shared(np.random.normal(0,1,layerShape[1]))
        self.output = T.nnet.nnet.sigmoid(T.dot(self.input,self.W)+self.b)

    def train(self, cost, rate):
        WGrad = T.grad(cost=cost, wrt=self.W)
        bGrad = T.grad(cost=cost, wrt=self.b)
        return [[self.W, self.W - WGrad * rate],
                [self.b, self.b - bGrad * rate]]

class Model(object):
    def __init__(self, inputNodes, hiddenNodes, outputNodes, rate):
        self.x = T.matrix()
        self.y_ = T.matrix()

        hiddenLayer = HiddenLayer(self.x, (inputNodes, hiddenNodes))
        outputLayer = OutputLayer(hiddenLayer.output, (hiddenNodes, outputNodes))
        self.layers = [hiddenLayer, outputLayer]

        self.y = outputLayer.output

        self.train = self.buildTrainOp(rate)
        self.infer = self.buildInferenceOp()

    def buildTrainOp(self, rate):
        cost = T.mean(T.sqr(self.y - self.y_))
        updates = [update for updates in [layer.train(cost, rate) for layer in self.layers] for update in updates]
        return theano.function(inputs=[self.x, self.y_], outputs=cost, updates=updates)

    def buildInferenceOp(self):
        return theano.function(inputs=[self.x], outputs=self.y)

nn = Model(2, 3, 1, 0.05)
print(nn.infer([[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]]))

xorTableX = [[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]]
xorTableY = [[i!=j] for i,j in xorTableX]
for i in range(100000):
    batchX = xorTableX
    batchY = xorTableY
    nn.train(batchX, batchY)

print(nn.infer([[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]]))
```

And if you have some tip about good practices and convention when using theano, I'd love to hear about it, too. Thanks!

** Edit: ** Interestingly, when adding a second hidden layer of the same size, the "wrong" output is [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]. But again, I'm still getting the correct output about half the time.

Comment: have you tried using cross entropy for the cost (`T.nnet.binary_crossentropy`)? And what do your training curves look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh! It was painfully obvious. This is why I shouldn't program late at night.

I switched to ReLU for my hidden layer to see what effect that would have on the NN but forgot to switch back to Tanh. Obviously ReLU wont allow for the negative weights required.